# Need to fix a few bugs (preprocessor directives)

Tags: c

**task condition:** Using the structure type and preprocessor directives, compile a program for input information about N types of computer equipment, which is known: manufacturer, type (printer, scanner, laptop, mouse, keyboard), color, model), get the price by the formula y = 3x ^ 2 + 4x-2, where x is the number of the option plus N. Sort the prices for computer equipment by the method of "bubbles" in ascending order.

```
#define N 5 
#define M 15
#define PRI(X) 3*X*X+4*X-2 
typedef struct Ctechnology 
{
    char firma[M];
    char type[M];
    int price[N];
} comp;
int main()
{
    comp a;
    printf("Firm, type, price - (y=3x^2+4x-2)\n ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a.price[N] = PRI(((i + 1)+N)); // there is a problem
        printf("%d) ", i + 1); 
        scanf("%s %s", a.firma, a.type);
        printf("\n                              | [%d] | Firm %10s | Type %10s | Price %10d |\n", i + 1, a.firma, a.type, a.price[N]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, for one `a.price[N]` is an out-of-bounds access (you probably mean `a.price[i]`).

Comment: Please review [homework guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: There is no actual question in your post. When posting in the future, ask one specific question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running

```
#define N 5 
#define M 15
#define PRI(X) 3*X*X+4*X-2 

price[N] = PRI(((i + 1)+N));
```

through `gcc -E` (which runs the preprocessor), we get

```
price[5] = 3*((i + 1)+5)*((i + 1)+5)+4*((i + 1)+5)-2;
```

In general, you may want to add parentheses around the `X`es in your directive, so they're correctly grouped no matter the input:

```
#define PRI(X) 3*(X)*(X)+4*(X)-2
```

->

```
price[5] = 3*(((i + 1)+5))*(((i + 1)+5))+4*(((i + 1)+5))-2;
```

Then, of course, there's the matter of `price[N]` always being an out-of-bounds access.